# Laravel forge SSL error with soketi app getting curl error

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, curl, openssl

I am using soketi.app on different server than my app is. Do you have an idea why I am getting cURL error 35: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for - with laravel forge? I have lets encrypt everything works and once per 2 days it stop working and I need to restart nginx and soketi.app, everything is up to date and I tried to create new VPS as well. I followed up laravel forge tutorial: https://blog.laravel.com/deploying-soketi-to-laravel-forge-part-2 thanks It worked for 7 months in a row and suddenly it started to do this. any advice on this? thanks a lot